# grouped barplot by another column

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

This may have been asked before, but couldn't find searching.

I'm trying to barplot of a variable called "pet" in my dataset called "habitat" which is categorical with 3 categories - "Y", "N", "Null".

The following code works:

```
>barplot(table(habitat$pet),main = "Pet Distribution", 
  xlab = "Pet categories", ylab = "count", col = c("darkblue"))
```

Now I have another binary column called "outcome". Is it easy to do a grouped barplot of frequencies by outcome?

I'm trying following, which isn't working:

```
>counts = table(habitat$pet[habitat$outcome == 0],habitat$pet[habitat$outcome == 1])
>barplot(counts,main = "Pet Distribution by Outcome", xlab = "Pet categories", 
    ylab = "count", col = c("darkblue","red"), beside = TRUE)
```

The error is in the " counts" part as the arguments don't have same length. Any other solution?

The data is like below:

```
ID   pet  outcome   
1     Y     1          
2     N     1
3     N     0
4     Y     0
...
```

Comment: Can you copy-paste a small part of your data set? Maybe something around 10 to 20 observations.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. I'm generating some sample data because your sample data don't seem to be representative (e.g. you've got no "NULL" entries).

```
# Generate sample data
set.seed(2017);
df <- data.frame(
    ID = 1:100,
    pet = sample(c("N", "Y", "NULL"), 100, prob = c(0.1, 0.8, 0.2), replace = T),
    outcome = sample(c(0, 1), 100, replace = T))

# Plot
ggplot(df, aes(pet)) + geom_bar()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I got what you are looking for but try the following code:

```
if(!require(ggplot2)){install.packages('ggplot2')
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = habitat, aes(x = pet)) +
 geom_bar(position = 'fill', aes(fill = outcome)) +
 labs(x = 'Pet Categories', title = 'Pet Distribution by Outcome') +
 scale_fill_manual(values = c('darkblue','red'))
```

Skip `position` argument if you're not seeking for a proportional stacked barplot.